# pass an object through jquery trigger

Tags: jquery, json, events, triggers

I'm trying to do something rather simple but I'm getting a strange result.  I have an event trigger that I'm using to pass a json object but when it gets through to the other side it's a function... I alert the result and it shows this:

example of alert sting:

```
alert('value of lattitude? ' + map.currentLatLng.lat);
```

result:

> value of lattitude? function () {return this[a];}

I've tried setting up the trigger both with and without the array literal wrapper:

```
$('body').trigger('updateLocation', [{lat:38.905003, lng:-77.066497}]);
$('body').trigger('updateLocation', {lat:38.905003, lng:-77.066497});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Google Maps API? Which version? jQuery does not have an `updateLocation` event, so I doubt it knows how to trigger one, unless it's a custom event type that you defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body').bind('updateLocation',function(event,obj){
    alert(obj.lng);
});

$('body').trigger('updateLocation', [{lat:38.905003,lng:-77.066497}]);
```

​

Comment: This is wildly inconsistent between instances, I have just used this solution to troubleshoot the same issue, however I already have many examples in the same project of passing a complete object through trigger with no fault, why do I need to arbitrarily wrap it as an array this time to prevent unintended behaviour?

Comment: Wrapping it in an array works because it is how you pass multiple parameters while maintaining each parameter type, and since there is only one it is returned as the default value while it's type is preserved. Didn't click for me at first either.