# jquery: pass an object to event handler using jquery trigger method

Tags: jquery

Following code for passing an object to event handler is not working:

```
$('a.another').live('click', function(e, data) {
        alert(data); // **alerts '[{isMachineClick:true}]'**
        alert(data.isMachineClick); // **alerts 'undefined'**
});

$('a.another').trigger('click', "[{isMachineClick:true}]");
```

Please have a look at this.

PS: solution provided at link [pass an object through jquery trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686949/pass-an-object-through-jquery-trigger/) is not working, so posting a new thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing only a string, and what's more the JSON inside the string is an array, not an object. Try this:

```
$('a.another').live('click', function(e, data) {
    alert(data[0].isMachineClick);
});

$('a.another').trigger('click', [{isMachineClick:true}]);
```

**UPDATE**: Didn't realize how this worked: using an array is correct, and each additional item becomes another argument. This is the correct code:

```
$('a.another').live('click', function(e, data, data2) {

    alert(data.isMachineClick);

    alert(data2.someOtherThing);
});

$('a.another').trigger('click', [{isMachineClick:true}, {someOtherThing:false}]);
```

Comment: hey Luke, thxs for the reply. I tested your code, no alert is coming. please check it. I will really appreciate if you point me an example showing how to pass an array, object and JSON to an event handler.

Comment: With the most recent version of jQuery (at least 1.x), can you not replace the .live() method with .bind() now?